# How to create elements from an array of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create elements from an array of objects in React, but nothing appears even though I can see the data with console.log. Why?

```
<Test
  myArray={[
    {
       name: "Website",
       url: "url",
    },
    {
       name: "GitHub",
       url: "url",
    },
  ]}
>
     name
 </Test>
```

In Test component:

```
{myArray.map((elem) => {
  <h1>
    {elem.name}
  </h1>;
  <h2>
    {elem.url}
  </h2>;
})}
```

Comment: What do you mean by create elements? Are you trying to map the contents of your array into your jsx?

Comment: Yes, I want to create h1 and h2 foreach object in array

Comment: Firstly, you're not returning anything in your `.map` loop. You need to return the JSX you want to render. Secondly, for JSX there needs to be **one** parent for any block of tags you have, so you'd have to wrap those header tags in a single React fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- First, you need to return in your [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Typically that is done by enclosing your JSX in parenthesis `()`
- Second, you must not have semicolons in your JSX or it won't compile
- Third, you must always have a **single parent element**, otherwise it won't compile (you can e.g. use `<>` and `</>` or `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>`)
- Fourth, you need to integrate your component into the page DOM, which I assume you've done (if you used some tools to create the project, all of this should be setup properly). Otherwise you wouldn't see anything rendered within a React component at all.

Here your example with all of the above mentioned errors fixed and as you can see, it is displayed:

```js
function Test({ myArray }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {myArray.map((elem) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h1>{elem.name}</h1>
          <h2>{elem.url}</h2>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test
    myArray={[
      {
        name: "Website",
        url: "url",
      },
      {
        name: "GitHub",
        url: "url",
      },
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```